# C# Sorting Strings only on first letter

Tags: c#, string, sorting, alphabetical

I'm trying to sort a list of strings in alphabetical order in C#. My code looks like this:

```
public static List<Result> sort(List<Result> listToSort)
{
    int listSize = listToSort.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
    {
       for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++)
       {
           if (listToSort[i].SN[0] < listToSort[j].SN[0])
           { 
               Result tempValue = listToSort[j];
               listToSort[j] = listToSort[i];
               listToSort[i] = tempValue;
            }
        }
    }

    return listToSort;
}
```

But it's only sorting it based on the first letter of a string. In other words, if I have a list like this:

> donald, abby, dave, bob, sam, pete

It will sort it like so:

> abby, bob, donald, dave, pete, sam

One would expect 'dave' to come before 'donald'..
Any ideas?

Comment: `if (listToSort[i].SN[0] < listToSort[j].SN[0])` - you're only ever evaluating the first letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are only sorting by the first letter that is why you are seeing this result. You can use [Enumerable.OrderBy - LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

```
List<Result> sortedList = listToSort.OrderBy(r=> r.SN).ToList();
```

Or for your current code you can modify your check to:

```
if (string.Compare(listToSort[i].SN,listToSort[j].SN) < 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using LINQ for this:

```
return listToSort.OrderBy(report => report.SN)
```

I'm assuming your `Report` class has a `string` property you want the list to be sorted by?

**EDIT**

Didn't notice that you'd already specified the `SN` property, have amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<Result> sort(List<Result> listToSort)
{        
    return listToSort.OrderBy(x=>x.SN[0]).ToList();
}
```

Comment: wow thanks man, that's brilliant! Works like a charm. Just had to take out the 'SN[0]' and replace with 'SN'

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++)
   {
       if (listToSort[i].SN[0] < listToSort[j].SN[0])
       {
```

You are

- only comparing on SN[0]. If SN is a string then that explains your main result.
- always using the same compare, whether  i < j  or  i > j

Best thing to do is to use a built-in sort. Linq's `OrderBy(lambda)` is the easiest but it creates a new list. For an in-place sort, use `List<T>.Sort(Comparer)`.

If you do have to do it yourself, look up a good sorting algorithm (wikipedia).

Comment: When I just say 'listToSort[i].SN' I get the error saying that the operator '<' cannot be applied to type string and string?

Comment: Correct, `<` et al are not overloaded for strings. Use `'listToSort[i].SN.CompareTo(listToSort[j].SN) < 0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're only ever evaluating the first letter. Try using the traditional sorting method:

```
    public static void Sort(List<Result> listToSort)
    {
        listToSort.Sort(new ResultComparator());
    }

    public class ResultComparator : IComparer<Result>
    {
        public int Compare(Result x, Result y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null) return 0;
            if (x == null) return 1;
            if (y == null) return 0;

            // compare based in SN
            return string.Compare(x.SN, y.SN);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It was happened because of comparing character of the first string (listToSort[i].SN[0] => which produces the first character of your input). If you want to compare the string values, you should use string.Compare() method.

--SJ